# Order CSV with two digit numbers

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I'm trying to create a leaderboard for a game, where after the game has been played, the python script accesses a CSV file (not ordered) and prints out the top 5 people with the highest score. Python seems to do this fine with single-digit numbers, but I can't get it to work with 2 digit numbers. Here is the code:

```
import csv
import operator

sample = open('csv_sample2.txt', 'r')

csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=',')

sort = sorted(sample, key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)
```

and here is the output:
(I just used placeholder names for now)

```
['Matt Damon', ' 12']
['Robin Williams', ' 14']
['Billy Crystal', ' 15']
['Minnie Driver', ' 17']
['Peter Sellers', ' 6']
['Robert De Niro', ' 8']
['Stanley Kubrick', ' 9']
```

and here is the original leaderboard file:

```
Matt Damon, 12
Robert De Niro, 8
Billy Crystal, 15
Peter Sellers, 6
Stanley Kubrick, 9
Robin Williams, 14
Minnie Driver, 17
```

How do I get it to order the numbers properly?

Comment: why do you sort the file but also read it as CSV?, use a key function like `lambda x : int(x[1])`

Comment: You have to convert the strings into integer values in order to get a suitable sorting.

Comment: `csv1` is defined, but not used at time of writing.  intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest simply reading the file with file.readlines() and then processing the finished results.

Input File:

```
Matt Damon, 12
Robert De Niro, 8
Billy Crystal, 15
Peter Sellers, 6
Stanley Kubrick, 9
Robin Williams, 14
Minnie Driver, 17
```

Code:

```
data = []
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    scores = f.readlines()
    # data is a list of tuples with a string name as the 
    # first value and a integer score as the second value
    data = [ ( s.strip().split(', ')[0], int(s.strip().split(', ')[1]) ) for s in scores ]

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)

for name, score in sorted_data:
    print(f'{name} got a score of {score}')

# Prints:
# Minnie Driver got a score of 17
# Billy Crystal got a score of 15
# Robin Williams got a score of 14
# Matt Damon got a score of 12
# Stanley Kubrick got a score of 9
# Robert De Niro got a score of 8
# Peter Sellers got a score of 6
```

To print out only the first five scores from the ordered list `sorted_data`, use a for x in range() loop:

```
for x in range(5):
    name, score = sorted_data[x]
    print(f'{name} got a score of {score}')
```

This for loop will run 5 times. It unpacks the name and score contained in the tuple stored at `sorted_data x`, and then prints out that data.

Comment: This one works thank you! Do you know how I would change the code to print just the top 5 people?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to show how to print just the top 5 people.

Comment: Thanks man, this is a huuuuuge help, you're a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Your data might not be recognized as numbers?

```
data = [['Matt Damon', ' 12'],
        ['Robin Williams', ' 14'],
        ['Billy Crystal', ' 15'],
        ['Minnie Driver', ' 17'],
        ['Peter Sellers', ' 6'],
        ['Robert De Niro', ' 8'],
        ['Stanley Kubrick', ' 9']]
# conversion to floats
data = [[item[0], float(item[1])] for item in data]

sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Gives me:

```
[['Peter Sellers', 6.0],
 ['Robert De Niro', 8.0],
 ['Stanley Kubrick', 9.0],
 ['Matt Damon', 12.0],
 ['Robin Williams', 14.0],
 ['Billy Crystal', 15.0],
 ['Minnie Driver', 17.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...: sample = [['Matt Damon', ' 12'],
    ...: ['Robin Williams', ' 14'],
    ...: ['Billy Crystal', ' 15'],
    ...: ['Minnie Driver', ' 17'],
    ...: ['Peter Sellers', ' 6'],
    ...: ['Robert De Niro', ' 8'],
    ...: ['Stanley Kubrick', ' 9']]
    ...:
    ...: def get_int_item(o):
    ...:     return  int(o[1])
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: sort = sorted(sample, key=get_int_item)
    ...:
    ...: for eachline in sort:
    ...:     print(eachline)
    ...:
['Peter Sellers', ' 6']
['Robert De Niro', ' 8']
['Stanley Kubrick', ' 9']
['Matt Damon', ' 12']
['Robin Williams', ' 14']
['Billy Crystal', ' 15']
['Minnie Driver', ' 17']
```

Comment: you may use tha lambda function sugested by @riov8

Answer (score 0):

The answer in your number is recognize by string, instead of integer.
**Try to convert the score by using int()**, but be carful not to input operator.itemgetter object. The int() function only takes string, bytes-like object or a number.

```
sample = open('csv_sample2.txt', 'r')
csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=',')
sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda k: int(k[1]))
```

If you do not want the space just use str.strip() to get rid of them.